# Java screen variable is null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm making a Point class in order to make points more easily. I want it to convert between my own coordinate system to the screen's coordinate system, but when I call the method getWidth, it says it is null and gives a NullPointerException. Here is my Point class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;

public class Point extends GameLoop{
public float X, Y;
private float scale;

public float getScale() {
    return scale;
}

public void setScale(float scale) {
    this.scale = scale;
}

public Point toScreenCoordinates(){
    return new Point(((this.X + scale)/2 * screen.getWidth()), ((this.Y + scale)/2 * screen.getHeight()));
}

public void drawImageHere(Image i, Graphics2D g){
    Point p = this.toScreenCoordinates();
    g.drawImage(i, Math.round(p.X) - i.getWidth(null)/2, (Math.round(p.Y) - i.getHeight(null))/2, null);
}

public Point(float x, float y){
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    scale = 1;
}

public void update(long timePassed) {

}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

}
}
```

Here is my GameLoop class which  contains the screen object:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Window;

public abstract class GameLoop {

private static DisplayMode[] modes = {
    new DisplayMode(800, 600, 32, 0),
    new DisplayMode(800, 600, 24, 0),
    new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, 0),
    new DisplayMode(640, 480, 32, 0),
    new DisplayMode(640, 480, 24, 0),
    new DisplayMode(640, 480, 16, 0)
};

private boolean running;
public Animation a;
public int fps;

public ScreenManager screen;

public void stopAll(){
    running = false;
}

public void run(){
    try{
        init();
        gameLoop();
    }finally{
        screen.restoreScreen();
    }
}

public void gameLoop(){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long cumTime = startTime;

    while(running){
        long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - cumTime;
        cumTime += timePassed;

        update(timePassed);

        Graphics2D g = screen.getGraphics();
        draw(g);
        g.dispose();
        screen.update();
        a.update(timePassed);

        try{
            Thread.sleep((1000 + (fps - (1000 % fps)))/fps);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}

public void init(){
    fps = 60;
    a = new Animation();
    screen = new ScreenManager();
    DisplayMode dm = screen.findFirstCompatibleMode(modes);
    screen.setFullScreen(dm);

    Window w = screen.getFullScreenWindow();
    w.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    w.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    w.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    running = true;
}

public abstract void update(long timePassed);
public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g);


}
```

And here is my ScreenManager class, which is the class that my screen variable is an object of:

```
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ScreenManager {

private GraphicsDevice vc;

public ScreenManager(){
    GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    vc = e.getDefaultScreenDevice();
}

public DisplayMode[] getCompatibleDisplayModes(){
    return vc.getDisplayModes();
}

public DisplayMode findFirstCompatibleMode(DisplayMode[] modes){
    DisplayMode goodModes[] = vc.getDisplayModes();
    for(int x = 0;x<modes.length;x++){
        for(int y = 0;y<goodModes.length;y++){
            if(displayModesMatch(modes[x], goodModes[y])){
                return modes[x];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean displayModesMatch(DisplayMode m1, DisplayMode m2){
    if(m1.getWidth() != m2.getWidth() || m1.getHeight() != m2.getHeight()){
        return false;
    }
    if(m1.getBitDepth() != DisplayMode.BIT_DEPTH_MULTI && m2.getBitDepth() != DisplayMode.BIT_DEPTH_MULTI && m1.getBitDepth() != m2.getBitDepth()){
        return false;
    }
    if(m1.getRefreshRate() != DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN &&         m2.getRefreshRate() != DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN && m1.getRefreshRate() != m2.getRefreshRate()){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public DisplayMode getCurrentDisplayMode(){
    return vc.getDisplayMode();
}

public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(f);

    if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
        try{
            vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }

    f.createBufferStrategy(2);
}

public Graphics2D getGraphics(){
    Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if(w != null){
        BufferStrategy s = w.getBufferStrategy();
        return (Graphics2D)s.getDrawGraphics();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

public void update(){
    Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if(w != null){
        BufferStrategy s = w.getBufferStrategy();
        if(!s.contentsLost()){
            s.show();
        }
    }
}

public Window getFullScreenWindow(){
    return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
}

public int getWidth(){
    Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if(w != null){
        return w.getWidth();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

public int getHeight(){
    Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if(w != null){
        return w.getHeight();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

public void restoreScreen(){
    Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if(w != null){
        w.dispose();
    }
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}

public BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int w, int h, int t){
    Window win = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if(win != null){
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = win.getGraphicsConfiguration();
        return gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h, t);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Java already has a `Point` class, [`java.awt.Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html), which already has conversion capabilities between local and screen context support, [`SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointToScreen(java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component))

Comment: It seems odd that your `Point` class would need to extend from `GameLoop` as it's not really adding any new functionality to that particular class and without further evidence, I would "guess" that you are creating an instance of `GameLoop` and another instance of `Point`, but `Point` doesn't initialise the `screen`

Answer (score 0):

You are only initializing the screen field in the init method of GameLoop, and that is only called from the run method.

When you construct your Point it makes its own screen field because it is a subclass of GameLoop. So it is not using the screen field of the GameLoop class your probably have.

You don't actually need to have Point extend GameLoop. But if you do you have to initialize Point's local version of screen in the constructor.